# Which event is called when leaving a tab in Xamarin Forms 5 Shell App

Tags: xamarin.forms

Which event is called when leaving a tab in Xamarin Forms 5 Shell App?

In one of my tabs, I play audio file. I need to pause the player while leaving to another tab.

I'm using [SimpleAudioPlayer](https://codexamarin.blogspot.com/2019/01/play-audio-in-xamarin-forms-using.html) to play audio. So I have full control to play, pause and resume the audio.
So while leaving the focus on the tab, I will use `player.Pause();` and while the user return back, I can use `player.Play();`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.multipage-1.currentpagechanged?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: @Rauf [Shell.OnNavigating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#navigation-deferral) event can be fired before leaving a tab, but not sure whether it is helpful for your problem.